# How to use Wix Toolset's HarvestDirectory?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, wix, windows-installer

I want to automatically add a folder, `C:\example\dir`, to a Wix Toolset MSI installer.

I used the [HarvestDirectory target](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/target_reference/harvestdirectory.html) like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <?include "Config.wxi" ?>
    <Product Id="*" Name="programName" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Me" UpgradeCode="2275bf6b-489e-49f3-a7fd-cfd96ed94d7b">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="programName" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="BinDirRefId" />
        </Feature>

        <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />

        <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="programName">
                    <Directory Id="BinDirRefId" Name="bin">
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <ItemGroup>
        <HarvestDirectory Include="C:\example\dir">
            <DirectoryRefId>BinDirRefId</DirectoryRefId>
        </HarvestDirectory>
    </ItemGroup>
</Wix>
```

Visual Studio tells me that `ItemGroup` isn't a valid child of `<Wix>`. How should I use this target exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the vcxproj or csproj, these are helpers for MsBuild, the ItemGroup needs to be added to the [wixproj](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/authoring_first_msbuild_project.html) too to simplify the build. Then you can use the same Directory id as the [example](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/wix-example-harvest-directory/blob/master/foo.wxs).

Same snippet adjusted to your attempt:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
  ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="foo.wxs" />
    <HarvestDirectory Include="C:\example\dir">
      <DirectoryRefId>BinDirRefId</DirectoryRefId>
      ...
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <WixExtension Include="WixUIExtension" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
</Project>
```

Comment: I have ad this harvestDirectory to my .wixproj and specify it like this:
<HarvestDirectory Include="bin\\x64\\Debug\\DLLs">
    <DirectoryRefId>dlls</DirectoryRefId>
    <ComponentGroupName>dlls</ComponentGroupName>
    <PreprocessorVariable>var.dlls</PreprocessorVariable>
</HarvestDirectory>
However when I try to rebuild visual studio says "Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:dlls' in section 'Product:*'."
the line that throws this error is : <ComponentGroupRef Id="dlls" />
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For all who come across this: I had the same problem which @ShinoLex is describing. I could solve it by using <HeatDirectory> instead of <HarvestDirectory>.  See https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/heatdirectory.html or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1107786/Enabling-Harvest-Heat-exe-in-a-Wix-Setup-Project